# Disabling Extensions in PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I need to disable all extensions within the chrome browser using Puppeteer. I used the `--disable-extensions` argument like below.

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
   Headless = true,
   ExecutablePath = ChromePath,
   IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true,
   Args = new[] { "--disable-extensions" },
});
```

When I try to load a file URL (for example https://winaero.com/downloads/Win7Games4Win10_8_81_v2.zip), the `Internet Download Manager` will pop up to start the download. I'm using the headless mode to hide everything and I have used `--disable-extensions` to disable any extension like `Internet Download Manager`.
Why is it not working? where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can disable the built in download manager with `--disable-extensions`.

Another approach if it is just `ZIP's` you want to stop is to plumb this code in:-

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.url().endsWith('.zip'))
        request.abort();
    else
      request.continue();
});
```

You may also want to lower case the url so you also trap `.ZIP` abnd `Zip` etc

Also on your goto you will need to abort the request e.g.

```
  await page
        .goto("https://winaero.com/downloads/Win7Games4Win10_8_81_v2.zip")
        .catch(r => r.abort);
```

Comment: how IDM capture links from chrome? how chrome let the url pass to IDM?

Comment: i am not sure I understand you. When you make a call to `page.goto` that is a ZIP it downloads it :)

Comment: I'm talking about third-party programs like `IDM` http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/. How they capture links and URLs from chrome so decide to download or not? Hope I'm clear :)

Comment: Ah I see, in that case you will need to intercept the request and abort it so IDM does not kick in at all. IDM is an external program and probably intercepts requests outside of the browser. That is it sniffs the network requests independantly